# Spark on YARN multitenancy

Tags: apache-spark

we are currently evaluating Spark on our cluster that already supports MRv2 over YARN.

We have noticed a problem with running jobs concurrently, in particular that a running Spark job will not release its resources until the job is finished. Ideally, if two people run any combination of MRv2 and Spark jobs, the resources should be fairly distributed.

I have noticed a feature called "dynamic resource allocation" in Spark 1.2, but this does not seem to be solving the problem, because it releases resources only when Spark is IDLE, not while it's BUSY.

I haven't been able to locate any further information on this matter. On the other hand, I feel this must be pretty common issue for a lot of users.

So,

1. What is your experience when dealing with multitenant MRv2 and Spark cluster with YARN?
2. Is Spark architectually adept to support releasing resources while it's busy? Is this a planned feature or is it something that conflicts with the idea of Spark executors?

Comment: We use dynamic allocation, works pretty well. I don't understand this line: "releasing resources while it's busy?" - why it should release resources if it need them. Also you can try to play with Yarn dynamic pools, for example set higher priority for MR jobs

Comment: Hi @EugeneZhulenev let me explain. User A of Spark run his job with utilization of 100 % resources to accomplish job as soon as possible, it takes 2 days. Meanwhile user B is going to run his job which takes 1 hour. Both users are ok with waiting for their jobs 2 hours longer. So is Dynamic Resource Allocation helpfull in case user A utilize 100 % of resources all the time? What if there are 10 users and the first can utilize all resources? What I am looking for is similar approch to MapReduce where a new user obtains fair share of resources. Is it possible with Spark? Thanks